# How to select same column data as different rows in SQL

Tags: sql

Using SQL Select Query with the table of following structure

```
Id  Name  Subject

07  anu   Maths
07  anu   English
07  anu   Hindi
```

I want the Result as

```
Id Name Sub1    Sub2     Sub3
07 Anu  Maths   English  Hindi
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help you

```
SELECT Name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Maths' THEN Subject ELSE NULL END) [subject1],
      MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'English' THEN Subject ELSE NULL END) [subject2],
      MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Hindi' THEN Subject ELSE NULL END) [subject3]
FROM Subject
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: No needed. Would be better as an example solution for question instead of just a link `;)`